# Add a 'loading' gif when an image is loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can l use jQuery to add a loading gif file when an image is loaded, without do it in code behind? For example to this line? Pls help.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hprImage" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("WebAddress")%>' ImageUrl='<%# ReturnFilePath((Eval("FileName")).ToString()) %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Your Code Example is not jQuery. It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve (load a loading gif when an image is already loaded), nor what you have tried. You may want to specify your problem a little more.

Comment: sorry but l'm dealing with some legacy code here, l spent few days but still can't figure it out how to do with the whole code. l think the code that could be changed is this line. The original code is using Telerik method....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("loading place").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).html("<img id='loading'/>")
});
```

Also, for more jQuery reference, please visit the [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/) or the [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/)!!

Comment: _"plz visit the jQuery website or the **w3cshcool**!!"_ I guess the downvotes will come soon... :) Update: I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Niklas well, normally I'm also a W3schools-hater, but You have to admit, they have some articles that are rather good and well explained. So, for people starting with Web-Stuff it's still a good resource.

Comment: @Panda Yang: can you explain about this line --> `$(this).html("<img id='loading'/>")`? how can l make this line work?

Comment: I think you'd batter look at those website before asking this question or you will get downvotes.

Comment: I think w3cschool is good enough for beginners. Articles there are simple to understand, also won't get lost easily.:)

Comment: Of course, if want more information and details description, we must use the official website. That's why I recommend two website for hakunabean since he looks like a very beginner in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I had used this hack once :

```
<div>
  <span id="id1">View image</span>  
  <div style="display:none;" id="spinner">
    <img src='/images/preloader.gif' width="16"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This was the function onClick of 'id1':

```
    function loadImage()
    {
        var spinnerObj = $('#spinner'); //Spinner until the image loads
        spinnerObj.show();
        var img = $("<img width='100px;' />").attr('src', 'http://www.foo.com/a.gif').load(function()
        {
       var imageDiv = spinnerObj.parent();
       imageDiv.html(img);
        });
    }
```